# How to set environment variables via publish profile in .NET Core console app?

Tags: c#, environment-variables, console-application, .net-6.0, backgroundworker

I have a .NET Core worker service app, I have different `appsetings.json` files like `appsetings.Dev.json`, `appsetings.Prod.json` etc. I want to load these appsettings file based on the environment variables provided via either Publish Profiles or command line publishes.

For example, in ASP.NET Core apps, I can add the following tag into .pubxml file

```
<PropertyGroup>
    <EnvironmentName>Dev</EnvironmentName>
</PropertyGroup>
```

For, ASP.NET Core web apps this will automatically set the environment as **Dev** and the release build will load the `appsetings.Dev.json` file.

For the background app, this approach doesn't work. How can I set environment variables for .net 6 worker apps?

I've also tried to supply environment variables via CLI, but the release build app always uses the environment as "Production" no matter what is provided (Staging, Development, QA etc.)

Comment: Seems like this isn't supported yet. Discussion on similar issues can be found here: https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/71104

Answer (score 0):

There are a few different ways to add env variables to your project

1. Can use *dotnet run* command, and pass env variables as parameter using *-p* flag. For example
    `dotnet run -p:Environment=Development -p:EnvVar=value1`
2. Using configuration files like appsettings.json to store values of env variables and read them at runtime. You can use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration library for it
3. Set ENV variables from code using this method
    `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("EnvVar", "secretkey");`

Environment variables set with the dotnet run command are only available during the execution of the command and they are not set globally in the system. On the other hand, by setting them through the Environment class or by modifying the environment in the machine or in the server, these variables will be available for all the applications running in the system/machine.

Comment: None of your approaches answers my question.
**1.** `dotnet run -p:Environment=Development -p:EnvVar=value1`  - this for running the app in local machine, not using a release build, right?

**2.** Using configuration files like appsettings.json to store values of env variables and read them at runtime. You can use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration library for it - if I store the environment variable in `appsettings.json` file how does that work to read the file `appsettings.{EnvironmentName}.json`?

Comment: **3.** Set ENV variables from code using this method - that is a hardcoded way to supply environment variables. Every time I have to change the code for a different release build (Staging, QA, Dev etc), right?

Comment: " by modifying the environment in the machine or in the server, these variables will be available for all the applications running in the system/machine." - why would you set the application-specific environment variable globally?

Comment: 1. If you are using pipelines then for each stage you can have parameters and use those variable parameters and pass them to run stage like this  -                                          task: AzureRmWebAppDeployment@4
  displayName: 'Deploy'
  inputs:
    AppSettings: '-variable1 ${{ parameters.variable1 }} -variable2 ${{ parameters.variable1 }}'
    ExcludeFilesFromAppDataFlag: false

Comment: my background app is registered as a Windows Service on the server, I'm not running it from a pipeline. There should be some way to provide environment variables while creating a release build, so the release build app can access the environment variables

Comment: Then have you tried to use https://github.com/bolorundurowb/dotenv.net ? With this package, you can create .env field for all your environments, and then get them

Comment: No I haven't used any third-party package, there should be an inbuilt functionality to provide and access environment variables for console/worker apps

Answer (score 0):

Configure your `.csproj` file with below lines

```
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Release'">
    <EnvironmentName>Production</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
  <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='QA'">
    <EnvironmentName>Quality</EnvironmentName>
  </PropertyGroup>
 <PropertyGroup Condition="'$(Configuration)'=='Dev'">
    <EnvironmentName>development</EnvironmentName>
 </PropertyGroup>
```

above lines checks your configuration name if that configuration is `Release` then your environment name will be `Production`,if that configuration is `QA` then your environment name will be `Quality`,if that configuration is `Release` then your environment name will be `development` in `Web.config` After publish in published folder.

Configure your `Program.cs` file as below

```
    builder.Configuration
      .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
      .AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true)
      .AddJsonFile($"appsettings.{Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT") ?? "Production"}.json", optional: true)
      .AddEnvironmentVariables()
      .Build();
```

if it is `Production` environment consume from `appsettings.Production.json` if Particular environment not found uses the `appsettings.json`

Comment: Your solution strictly ties to the environment as **Production** for a Release build. How do you set other environment variables (Staging, QA, Dev etc) for the release build?

Comment: @Sultan While Publishing Check your configuration write logic for different in .csproj file. after publish check your web.config file in published folder set environment variable based on configuration

Comment: Does the `web.config` file has any impact on the console app hosted as a windows service?
as far as I know, `web.config` file is required for IIS-hosted applications

Comment: yes. It check's for key value pair's while application is starting. in this it checks for `<environmentVariable name="ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT" value="Staging" />`

Comment: I think you didn't understand my question. Does a windows service app read the environment from `web.config` file?

Comment: There is no web.config genereated for console apps. So the environment variable is never set.